# create a progress-bar in the form

Tags: progress-bar, formsflow.ai, formsflow

I was trying to create a progress bar in my form. The progress bar is supposed to be updated each time when I complete different fields so that the progress bar will be completed when all the fields are filled.

I was pretending that there will be a component to drag and drop. But its not there in the component section.

Can I get a way out to create a progress bar in the the form?

Comment: What tools/programming language are you using? Also, I can see you provided 2 different answers to your own question. I'm unsure whether they are supposed to provide additional information (in which case you should edit the question and add the information there), or whether one of them actually provides the answer to your own question. In that case, provide a single answer, and mark it as solved. Ideally, you elaborate more on what exactly you did, and show some code. As things are now, the answers, to me at least, look confusing, and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the html component which is given in the components section to add progress bar element. insert the ui code and connect the javascript values to update the progress bar dynamically.

[image: progress bar]

Add your html code here

[image: progress bar]

The saved result would be like the following image.

[image: progressbar html element in formsflow.ai]

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to add a progress bar to the form

[image: Progress Bar]

What I have done here is just added some Html content instead of the title of the compnent.

[image: add html as the title]

You can use any html progress bar componets to achieve this
I used a sample code from ww3Schools and the refernce is given
[sample code](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar1&stacked=h)

have a try on [formsflow.ai](https://formsflow.ai/)
and [form.io](https://www.form.io/)